# Conflicting computations when attempting to diagonalize the matrix of a linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

I am given the following matrix of a linear operator A, and asked to diagonalize it. 
$$
  A = \begin{pmatrix}
    -2 & 2 & 6 \\
    5 & 1 & -6 \\
    -5 & 2 & 9\\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$ 
Solving for $det(A-\lambda I) = 0$, I have the following eigenvalues:

$\lambda = 3 , \lambda = 3,   \lambda = 2$ (counting multiplicities).

For $\lambda = 3$ , $Ker(A-\lambda I)$ has the basis $\begin{pmatrix}
\frac25 \\
1 \\
0
\end{pmatrix}
$ and $\begin{pmatrix}
\frac 65 \\
0 \\
1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$ , which are the eigenvectors corresponding to $\lambda = 3$.

On the other hand, for $\lambda = 2$ , this is where I have some confusion.

We want to find the nullspace of $(A-2I) = \begin{pmatrix}
-4 & 2 & 6 \\
5 & -1 & -6 \\
-5 & 2 & 7 \\
\end{pmatrix}$. Computing the reduced echelon form of the matrix of $(A-2I)$ , I get $\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$ (without row swap operations) and conclude that the nullspace $Ker(A-2I)$ is trivial. As such, I conclude the geometric multiplicities and algebraic multiplicities of the eigenvalues do not coincide and hence the linear operator A cannot be diagonalized.

However, in the solution given, row exchange operations are performed when computing the reduced echelon form of $(A-2I)$. Rows 1 and 2 are swapped such that eventually, the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}
-4 & 2 & 6 \\
5 & -1 & -6 \\
-5 & 2 & 7 \\
\end{pmatrix}$ is reduced to $\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$ (which eventually leads to A being diagonalizable).

Why is that so? I tried verifying my computations for basis vectors in the nullspace $Ker(A-2I)$ with several online calculators, and all of them indicate that $Ker(A-2I)$ is trivial and no row exchanges take place in computing this. Aren't these results conflicting? One says that $Ker(A-2I)$ is trivial, while the other eventually leads to $Ker(A-2I)$ having the basis $\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
-1 \\
1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You forgot a minus sign on the $2,3$ entry of the second $(A - 2I)$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Oh, this is embarassing! Thanks for pointing it out, my dilemma is resolved!